# Get an specific value of css class, using d3js

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have an HTML table and I want to set the color of an specific part of the table (border-top-color of a cell classed "first"). 
To get the color I need to access to an specific value within a css class.

Example:

Table

```
<table class="tabla">
    <caption>Title</caption>
      <tr>
        <td class="first">A</td>
        <td class="first">157</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

CSS
This is the class where I need to be able to get the color

```
.color { fill: #95ccee;
         background-color: #95ccee;
         }
```

To achieve, I'm using d3.js in the follow way

```
var selectTablas = d3.selectAll (".tabla");
    selectTablas.selectAll(".first")
                .style("border-top-color", "Here the function that will get the color");
```

The function should loop a dataset and, depending of the "d", get different values of different classes.

Here, the extended code

http://jsfiddle.net/ploscri/dHYcd/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's one vital piece missing here -- how do you want to map "d" (which I assume is the "Diff" column?) to colors? Based on ranges? Some sort of hex conversion? Is there a max an min range that the difference could be? Do you have a specific color mapping method in mind? If you add these details I'd happily add an answer : )

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's my first stab at it. The question isn't super clear, but this function provides you with a way to pass a class name into it and retrieve the color on that class. I updated your example with the color you have in the question. I assume you have a function somewhere else that maps the difference value into a classname.

http://jsfiddle.net/dHYcd/1/

First thing I did here was make a container of hidden classes that carry the colors for testing. In order to grab the value from the css, it needs to be present in the html, which I assume it is already somewhere. If it's not I have no idea why you'd be doing it this way rather than just defining the color in the javascript.

```
<div id='colors'>
    <span class='color1'></span>
</div>
```

Next, added the css declaration that you have in your question but was not in the jsfiddle, but changed out `fill` and `background-color` for just `color`. I also made sure the div containing the colors was hidden so it wouldn't interfere with the example.

```
#colors { display: none }
#colors .color1 { color: #95ccee }
```

Finally, the function to actually get the color from the class is fairly simple. The code is reproduced below:

```
function get_color(classname){
    var el = document.querySelector('#colors .' + classname);
    return getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue('color');
}
```

This function just grabs an element based on a class name that you provide as an argument, then grabs the css value of `color`. You can see that it would be easy to swap out `color` if you wanted to get another property value, or even to add the property value as a second argument to the function, but I didn't see a need for this in this example.

Hope this helps, and if this isn't quite what you were after, I apologize, the question was a little difficult to interpret. Feel free to add a comment or edit to clarify the question and I'll update the answer to get closer to what you are after (if I didn't nail it this time).

**EDIT**

OP clarified that they are looking for the best way to store color values and figured it would be in the css. I would say this is not the best way to store color values, and recommend storing them in an object in the javascript, since they are only needed in the javascript. Here is an updated fiddle that stores the colors in a better way:

http://jsfiddle.net/dHYcd/2/

If you change `colors.blue` to `colors.red` you'll see that you can easily swap between the different colors, and the syntax is native to javascript anyway.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I apologize for the unclear question. This is a small part of a bigger project. I have global css classes with colors values (".color" in my eg.) and I use those classes to set the color of different elements in the DOM. This works fine with the objects that are allowed to use the background-color or fill property (sometimes I use the classes to set the color of an SVG element). But sometimes I need to set the color of a part of an element (eg. border-top-color) and I want to get the color from the class. I can't change the structure of the classes. Is there a way to do it?.

Comment: Yes, my entire answer was exactly that - a function that allows you to get a property value from a CSS class. Was there something missing in there? Happy to expand or clarify if you let me know precisely what the missing piece is.

Comment: Hi, Jeff. What I need is a method to get the value of a css class without an element in the DOM. In your answer you use an element (#color)  to grab the value from the css. I dont want to write in the javascript the color because I want to keep the colors in one place, the css clases. Probably my approach for the app is not the best, I'm not a programer I'm trying to learn about it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah, if you are not going to have an element in the DOM, there is no reason to have css for it. I edited the answer and added my recommended method of storing the colors to the end, hope this helps a little more!